# JAVA "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, static

I come from C++ and started with Java. So I know i cant use super and this in static functions but whats wrong with the code?

```
class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test x = new Test(); // Here is the error Why? 
    }

    class Test {
        //attributes 
        String attribute;
    }
}
```

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`Test` class is an inner class of `TestClass` class. Therefore, in order to create an object of `Test` class, you must create an object of the enclosing `TestClass` class.

You can fix this error by moving `Test` class outside `TestClass`:

```
class Test {
    //attributes 
    String attribute;
}

class TestClass { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test x = new Test();
    }  
}
```

or by making it a nested (static) class (which doesn't require an enclosing instance):

```
class TestClass { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test x = new Test(); 
    }  

    static class Test {
        //attributes 
        String attribute;
    }
}
```

If you insist on keeping `Test` an inner class, you can write:

```
class TestClass { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass.Test x = new TestClass().new Test(); 
    }  

    class Test {
        //attributes 
        String attribute;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, `Test` is non-static class and trying to access it from static context (i.e. from main() method, which is static), which means you need to create the instance/object of `TestClass` class first.

```
Test x = new Test();
```

It should be

```
TestClass.Test x = new TestClass().new Test();
```

---

Or declare `Test` as static.

```
static class Test {
    //attributes 
    String attribute;
}
```